# change the content of the element behind another element

Tags: jquery

I was testing something out to see if I could change the element before the select element based on the select changing:

```
<input type="text" id="change" />
<select>
    <option>some</option>
    <option>thing</option>
    <option>test</option>
</select>

$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).prev().text("it has changed");
});
```

I thought using the `prev()` method would have been the fight way to go, but I think it only looks for elements of the same type? according to the documentation (as I understood it).

Is there a way I can go directly to the previous element and just change the contents?

Comment: Use `.val()` function. Might this help http://jsfiddle.net/BUFD7/. However simply `$('#change').val('it has changed')` will do.

Comment: @Satpal How do I mark that as the answer? XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function instead of `.text()`.

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).prev().val("it has changed");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BUFD7/)

However, As you have specified id to the input, simply `$('#change').val('it has changed')` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

> but I think it only looks for elements of the same type?

No not at all. [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/YX374/)

Code:

```
$(".yeah").prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

where `.yeah` is an `a`nchor element and its previous sibling is a `div`

So, you can be assured that your code works (when you change `.text` to `.val` ofcourse)

You could also use, `$('#change').val('it has changed')`, but then, if any element is added dynamically before the `select`, then you would have to use the `.prev` function only.

Answer (score 0):

use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(this).prev().val("it has changed");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="change" />
<select>
    <option>some</option>
    <option>thing</option>
    <option>test</option>
</select>


$("select").change(function() {
        $value=$(":selected").text();
        $("#change").val($value)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this..

```
$("select").change(function() {
$(this).prev().text("it has changed");
}).change();
```